# Finding $y^{\prime}$ of $y=\log_7 e^{8x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Find $y^{\prime}$ of $y=\log_7 e^{8x}$

I know that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^{8x})=8e^{8x}$, but I am confused on how to work the rest of the problem.

Is this correct:

- $\log_ex=\ln x$ and that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\dfrac{y^{\prime}}{y}=\dfrac{1}{x}.$ (Can you show why $\log_ex=\ln x$ )
- $y=\log_b(x) \implies b^y=x \implies \ln(b^y)=\ln(x) \implies y\ln(b)=\ln(x)  \implies y=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}$
- $\dfrac{d}{dx}\log_b(x)=\dfrac{1}{x\ln(b)}$
- $\log_a(x^p)=p\log_ax \implies \log_7(e^{8x})=8x\log_7e$
- $y^{\prime}=\dfrac{8e^{8x}}{e^{8x}\ln(7)}=\dfrac{8}{\ln(7)}$

The various different notations just confuse me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. An easier way to proceed is by noting that

$$y = x \cdot (8 \log_7 e) = x \cdot \left(8 \frac{\ln e}{\ln 7}\right) = x \cdot \frac{8}{\ln 7}$$

by the change of base formula for logarithms.

Answer (score 3):

Simply we have

$$y=\log_7 e^{8x}=\frac{\ln e^{8x}}{\ln 7}=\frac{8x}{\ln 7}\Rightarrow y'=\frac{8}{\ln 7}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y=\log_7 e^{8x}=8x\log_7 e$$
$$y'=8\log_7 e=\frac{8}{\ln 7}$$

Comment: Nice Adi ${}{}{}{}$ :-)